# How to build a predictive model on Time series data

Tags: r, predictive-modeling, time-series, regression, visualization

I have a time series data containing hotel occupancy rates from January 2014 to December 2017. I have run a forecasting model (Holtswinter in R). Now, I want to predict the significant external factors driving this occupancy rate. I have considered weather data (Temperature, Visibility etc.,) and Google Trends data (based on certain key words for trend tracking) as Independent variables and Occupancy rate as Dependent variable. This is clearly a non-linear regression model. What is the best algorithm to predict the significant variables impacting occupancy rate? Please refer to the sample data in the image.[image]

Any insights on how to proceed with the model and/or any code snippets in R is/are surely appreciated. Thank you!